# From laravel controller passing value to ajax then get the particular field

Tags: javascript, laravel

how can i get the ID or Name Field then append it to Textbox, Please Correct me if i'm approaching this in the wrong way.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var students = {!! json_encode($students->toArray()) !!};

    //This Part Im Trying to get.
    var name=$(students).val(name);
    var id=$(students).val(id);

    console.log(name);

});
```

**Controller:**

```
 $students=Student::all()->take(5);
 return view('Examples.levels',compact('students'));
```

image below is the result if i use `console.log(students)`
[image]

**Updated Version**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var students = {!! json_encode($students->toArray()) !!};
    students.forEach(function(student) {
  $('.content').append(
  `<input name="name[]" value=`+student.name+`>`
  );
  console.log(student.name)
});
});
```

**Attached imaged result:**
[image]

Comment: There are some problems. first, your jquery selector, I mean, where you want to show your output, and second, there are 5 students data. which student data you want to show?

Comment: 1. how to get the name only. 2.Append all 5 student in a input field

Comment: what is the input field's selector? I mean, the input field name / id ?

Comment: Something like this <input type="text" id="student_name" name="student_name">

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Comment: Do you want to show the names on different inputs? or only one input.?

Comment: it should out-put 5 input fields something like loop them into an input field then attached the value to its attribute,

Comment: i tried this but does't work i'm only gettng one field populated rest of the 4 is empty.(students.forEach(function(student) {
     $('.content').append('<input type="text" id="myinput" name="id">'); 
     $("#myinput").val(student.name);)

Comment: @Copain Why don't you simply do this with blade ?

Comment: trying to play around with ajax

Comment: @Copain Your above code cannot work as you're using IDs which are unique in HTML. So jQuery selects only the first one even if you have 5 of them. Use classes instead.

Comment: @Steve Chamaillard hello can u tell me what are those? or can send link for me to read and learn on it..

Comment: @Copain Looking for "HTML class" in DDG : https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_classes.asp is the first link.

Comment: @ Steve Chamaillard thanks.. i end up using AJAX in controller it self return it as json response then use ajax in view thats the best way so far..hehe thanks for ur advice..$.get method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one. it will append with value.

```
students.forEach(function(student) {
  $('.content').append(
  `<input name="name[]" value="`+student.name+`">`
  );
});
```

Comment: whith this code above it is joining all into one input field , how can i break this like output this to 5 input fields

Comment: well. do you have 5 input fields? or you want to generate by js?

Comment: yes! ..i want it to be generated by js. like append with attribute

Comment: check my question i have update, almost there but its giving me weird output..

Comment: soryy my bad. I mistook one thing. now updated. try that one.

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over a students array like so:

```
students.forEach(function(student) {
   console.log(student.name);
   console.log(student.id);
});
```